# Algorithm for pairing people using messages

Tags: algorithm

Imagine you've got a bunch of people who all want to find a partner from among that bunch of people. Each person can make an announcement to the whole group, or to any specific person. The goal is that they all end up in pairs where possible.

New people can enter the group *while the pairing process is going on*. Once two people are paired as optimally as possible, they drop out of the group.

Each person has a "score" for each other person. People should be paired with higher-scoring partners where possible. However, it is more important that people find pairs at all than that those pairs are strictly optimal. So it is reasonable, for example, to have two people "provisionally paired" and then wait a bit to see if a better partner for either comes along; if one does not, then properly pair the two and they drop out of the group.

There is no central controlling entity: all the work has to be done by passing messages between people (or broadcast to the whole group).

What's the best algorithm for doing so?

Obviously the problem I'm trying to avoid is that A randomly chooses B and says "hey, be my partner" and at the same time B says to C "hey, be my partner". Also, A can't just announce "someone be my partner!" because A will get responses back from everyone, and if B has also announced "someone be my partner" should B respond to A's announcement or not?

This is similar-ish to the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem but (a) that's about finding a "stable" (strictly optimal) solution, which is useful but not required in my problem, and (b) it assumes the group is fixed in size and doesn't change, whereas my problem allows new entrants to the group while the "pairing election" is going on.

Comment: Interesting problem! Can you shine a light on your intended use, then it is easier to propose ideas. For instance, should the system be incentive compatible? That seems tricky for this particular case.

Comment: I don't think I know what "incentive compatible" means?

Comment: In game theory, if you let the agents (people in this case) decide something, you want to prevent them from "cheating". In this case, it would be sort of cheating if all people wait forever, afraid to bond before a their perfect match shows up. Do you want to prevent strategies like that?

Comment: I do want to prevent strategies like that, but my plan there is to basically have a timeout: choose a provisional partner (somehow) as early as possible, trade for a better partner whenever you can, and at the end of the timeout, go with whoever your provisional partner is.

Comment: Is the timeout known in advance? How much worse is a solution when two people remain unpaired than a suboptimal pairing score?

Comment: Are scores commutative? Do you automatically "know" the score with everyone else or do you have to send them a message to get to know them? If you don't, do you at least know the minimum and maximum score  possible in the group?

Comment: @biziclop: the message you get from a person "introducing" themselves gives you enough information to calculate your score for them. Remaining unpaired is much much worse than a suboptimal pairing.

Comment: @biziclop: scores are not commutative: I might give you a high score (meaning that I want to pair with you a lot) while you give me a low score (meaning you don't want to pair with me if you can avoid it).

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to give a method for describing the "goodness" of a pairing, or what information is needed to determine that. For example, can I know my "goodness" of fit with someone without messaging them? Do I have perfect information? In this case there are some well known and fast network flow type formulations which will find the best total solution. As long as everyone "independently" comes to this conclusion there will be no problem.

Its also extremely important to know if this goodness measure is symmetric. Is the score(A,B) = Score(B,A)? Transitivity is also useful if it can be established. But that seems unlikely.

If on the other hand, I need to message someone to find out our fit, then we have a menu type problem. Look up, for example, [Feynmann's Restaurant problem](http://www.feynmanlectures.info/exercises/Feynmans_restaurant_problem.html), which tells you how many dishes you should try in a menu of fixed size if you want to get maximum utility from some number of selections.

Its also unclear if you intended this to be a representative agent type problem (everyone has to use the best solution) or a game theory type solution (what should a user to to maximise their personal score). For example, the best solution might be some kind of mixed equilibrium, where some people broadcast their attributes, and other people work out their scores and approach the best looking.

This is a fascinating problem, but I am not sure that it is very well defined yet.

Comment: Agreed it's rather handwavily defined. A person's "hi, I exist" message contains enough information for everyone else to evaluate their goodness of fit with that person without further messages (thus calculating the "score" mentioned in the original). Scores are not symmetric; my score for you may be high while yours for me is low. Speed is, as noted, more important than being totally optimal; I'm not sure whether that means more a game theory approach or an agent approach.

Comment: Its not so much two different approaches, as two different goals. Is an individual trying to optimise their score, or are people jointly trying to optimise the community score? Obviously if accuracy is not at all important you can just pair off randomly, very fast. Also, being too fast is likely negative once the initial pool is used up, as every time two people join they automatically get paired immediately.

Comment: An individual is trying to optimise their own score; for the moment we do not care if the community as a whole is optimal. So we don't want literally random pairings, because if you pair two people with low scores for each other then they won't want to talk to one another!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need a "stick or twist" weighting for each pair to allow 'good enough' exit, think "closing time at the disco".

Each person starts with some stickiness factor = 0.
Start by choosing a provisional partner (through some reasonable heuristic/random hash/whatever)

Then iterate over something like this:

1. if your provisional partner has chosen you too, you are a pair
2. if your provisional partner has not chosen you yet, and you are 'sticky enough', they remain your provisional partner
3. if your provisional partner has not chosen you yet, and you are 'not sticky enough': choose another partner
4. if a suitor has stuck around, consider them more attractive in the next round
5. if you're still in the running, increase your 'stickiness'

Comment: Agreed on the general concept, but remember that there is no central authority. So how do I "choose a provisional partner"? There's no list of people that I can look at. All I can do is broadcast a message to everyone, or broadcast a message to someone I know exists. I could broadcast "hi! introduce yourself!" and everyone will reply, but everyone else is doing the same thing too.

Comment: If you're publishing a message, I guess you have some message broker. It should be able to publish to some subset of available nodes through some channel or namespace scheme.

Comment: If you have no broker, each node will need to build a largely redundant list of potential partners so even if you can stagger the message broadcast, you will suffer relatively high memory use.

Comment: There is, for the purposes here, no message broker. Agreed that each node will need to build the list of potential partners, and in my current design I have a "hello everyone!" broadcast message sent by each person joining the group so that everyone knows they exist. I'm not worried about high memory because this is distributed; each node is someone's web browser.

Comment: In the genuine no-broker form I think you're stuck with the "hello everyone" messages and using responses to build each node's feasible list of partners and rely on limiting responses to keep message load down. You could try sending "hello, I've been waiting n rounds for partnering" and having some "receptivity" parameter on each node to determine whether they respond to or ignore "hello, I've been waiting for n>receptivity rounds" when building nodes' feasible sets of partners.

Comment: Just an addition to the "stick or twist" algorithm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWib5olGbQ0

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the number of people involved, you might be able to store all the incoming data in one client and sent it along with the message when the client broadcasts itself. 
Example:

right now only 3 people A B C

A broadcasts

B stores, { A , msg:xxx }

B broad casts { A, msg:xxx } { me (B) , msg:yyy }

A stores, {B, msg:yyy}

C stores, { A , msg:xxx }, { B, msg:yyy }

D joins, broad cast with get all person request

A sends back { B, msg:yyy } { me(A), msg:xxx }

B sends back { A, msg:xxx} {me (B), msg:yyy}

C is not broad casting so not sending anything

D processes all the incoming requests and do some analysis to determine possible people in the area

A and B matches

A, B broadcasts remove A, B

C stores, {}

D stores, {}